# Backbone giving undefined for custom id attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a composite key in my database consisting of id and version. I'm using the same id for different versions of the same record. Backbone was merging the models with the same ID's, well since they had the same id's. So after looking around a bit, I modified the parse function of my model.

```
parse: function(response, options) {
  response.id = response.id + '_' + response.version;
  return response;
}
```

This is quite straightforward and everything was working fine, I can display multiple records with the same id and different versions. The weird behaviour begins when I try to save my model. Within my view I have a saveClickHandler, which sends the model to the backend for storing.

```
onSaveClick: function(e){
  // Some form validation which is not very relevant I think
  var self = this,
  data = {
    enabled:      Input.isChecked('enabled', this.$el)? true: false,
    days:         Input.get('days', this.$el),
    from_name:    Input.get('from_name', this.$el),
    reply_to:     Input.get('reply_to', this.$el),
    subject:      Input.get('subject', this.$el),
    content_html: Input.get('message', this.$el),
    postmark_tag: Input.get('postmark_tag', this.$el)
  };

  this.model.save(data, {
    url: Application.Config.URL_API + '/emails/' + self.model.get('id').split('_')[0] + '/' + self.model.get('id').split('_')[1],
  });
}
```

The first time after I load the page and store the record, everything goes fine, the record is updated in the database and all. However the second time the request fails because the id's are undefined.

Actually even before doing the save, I log the model of the view and the id is being changed from e.g. 10_1 to undefined_undefined. I'm not explicitly modifying the model itself, so I suppose that it has to do with backbone modifying it somehow.

Does anybody have any idea what the issue I'm encountering could be?

Comment: i'm guessing that it can't find your new id in an existing map of objects in the collection.

Comment: @DanielA.White But all of the records I'm displaying there are existing records, I'm not creating new records, just modifying the attributes of those records.

Comment: exactly! you are changing its ID but backbone is likely expecting them not to change

Comment: Hmmm, ok but then how should I let backbone know about my composite PK if not by modifying the parse function and concatenating them? Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Comment: perhaps your rest service should handle that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out some more things, it seems that when I submitted an update to a particular record, I am receiving this response:

```
{"success":true,"code":204,"message":"ok","result":null}
```

So I thought lets see if the parse() I implemented messes things up. So I changed my parse to:

```
parse: function(response, options) {
    if (response.id){
        response.id = response.id + '_' + response.version;
        return response;
    }
}
```

After testing it, everything seems to be working fine. So I suppose that because of the result being null it couldn't find an ID, therefore undefined_undefined. It all makes perfect sense now actually.

Thanks both of you for your replies, hopefully this can save some time to somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your architecture is sub-optimal here. Changing the model's ID is a solution to a problem which could be solved better by designing your app and api to handle versioning differenlty. Also you're missing out on the benefits of Backbone's convention-over-configuration philosophy.

One model and one id per database record, accessed by one resource endpoint should be the goal. This could be solved in a couple of ways.

Have your API return models with a version history in addition to the current values:

```
// GET /model response

{
  "id",
  "foo" : "foo",
  "bar" : "bar",
  "versions" : [
    {
      "version_id" : 1,
      "foo" : "foo1",
      "bar" : "bar1"
    },
    {
      "version_id" : 2,
      "foo" : "foo2",
      "bar" : "bar2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank way you can still listen to change events on the current values of the model's properties while retaining the version history.

Another, perhaps more appropriate way to solve it is to use a collection and have the API return a separate model for each version. This would also be a cleaner REST approach for the API since both the model and its versions would have their own endpoints, e.g. /model/version and all of Backbone's built-in CRUD operations would function correctly without you having to override anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I understand your point here, but using a composite primary key was a solution that I used to in another place to reduce the complexity of that part. The composite key solution (id and version), work fine for the rest of the issues, and the only issue I'm having is in the front-end. The other way around would make the rest of the application more complex. There isn't any way to make backbone aware of composite keys?

Comment: Backbone core: no. Backbone is meant to be a minimal framework (only ~800 lines of code!). You might be able to find some 3. party package that patches Backbone to make it do this. But if you go that route, you might want to take a look at https://ampersandjs.com which is very much like Backbone, but is actually designed with extendability in mind.